# Automation of Android APK with UI Automator

Tags: android

I want to automate an Android app using Google firebase test lab. I came to know that there are 2 tools with which we can do this.

Espresso & UI Automator: To use Espresso we need the App source code, but while reading some articles I came to know that we doesn't need App source code for UI Automator. I have even tried to use app source code of an hybrid app and found that there is only one element for App and not able to proceed.

Can someone help me how to automate an android app using UI Automator without app source code. I have my apk with me and not able to find any solution to run automation scripts using it.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to automate android APK without source code is to use Selenium WebDriver, Appium or some similar framework, especially when it is not a native application.

For native applications, I strongly suggest to use Espresso.

Comment: Thanks for your response!
But we would like to test Native application, but my client is not ready to give app source code but client want us to use Google fire base test lab only and not Selenium or Appium . Any suggestions?